# Target an id in html from jquery and make all others of it's kind disappear

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to ask that if in html say you have a few links, they're all part of the same class but have different IDs such as

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

I would have a jquery(script) where if I click link 1, link 2 and 3 would disappear but link 1 would glow.
Is there anyway to do this easily? I'm basically asking if there is any way to target all elements of a specific class and make them disappear other than the one you have clicked/hovered over.

Comment: Very very particular, I'm sure it has never been asked before...

Comment: @DidierGhys it is particular to thousand other guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function to exclude an element from a set of matched elements:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 10px blue');
    $('a').not(this).hide();
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eexen/1/).

Comment: Could you include a link to http://api.jquery.com/not/ in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the jQuery's `.siblings()` method

in your case it would look like:

```
$('.someClass').click(function(  ){

  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.2);

});
```